# What is the purpose of a protocol with no requirements?

Tags: swift

Doing a little deep diving and I came across this. What is the point of an empty protocol declaration? All I can think of is organization, but is that the only reason? Does it have any functional benefits?

[image]

Comment: To "link" possible objects that aren't related. `extension NSNumber : NSFetchRequestResult {};extension NSDictionary : NSFetchRequestResult {}; extension NSManagedObject : NSFetchRequestResult {}; extension NSManagedObjectID : NSFetchRequestResult {};`, and then `open class NSFetchRequest<ResultType> : NSPersistentStoreRequest, NSCoding where ResultType : NSFetchRequestResult {`, so instead of "Any" you have a "limited" "result kind".

Comment: @Larme And I assume that helps efficiency?

Answer (score 3):

It's just a way of bringing disparate types under one roof. A fetch result request can return any of four types: NSDictionary, NSManagedObject, NSManagedObjectID, or NSNumber. We need a way to say that. They are unrelated otherwise, so making them all adopt a common protocol is the way.

Thus NSFetchRequest is able to be a generic parameterized over one of those types without having to say which one it is.

```
open class NSFetchRequest<ResultType> : 
    NSPersistentStoreRequest, NSCoding 
    where ResultType : NSFetchRequestResult {
```

Whatever ResultType may be, it must conform to NSFetchRequestResult — and that means (at the moment) that it is one of those four classes.

Comment: I am piggy backing here but do you know what role NSFetchRequestResultType plays here? It contains constants for the 4 types you mentioned but it is in any way useful for us developers or is it only needed for the Core Data framework itself?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I'd say it's a hold-over from before there were generics. There had to be _some_ way for a fetch request to tell you which type it was returning. :) But now, in Swift, you'll just know; the fetch request itself is a generic and everything cascades from there. But my core data experience is not deep, so I might be wrong.